# Controlling DC motors in C# with DRV8835 and Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

After long searching I decided to ask here.
How can i control DC motors with Pololu DRV8835 Motor Driver?
I tried to use `Microsoft.IoT.Lightning` library, but frequency seems to be too low. In [Python library](https://github.com/pololu/drv8835-motor-driver-rpi) for this driver frequency is 20 kHz.
When I tried to modify this library, build threw exception because of non-existing targets (but they didn't even appeared after library building).

This is my code:

```
public async Task Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
            {
                throw new Exception("No lightning provider detected!");
            }

            LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();

            Gpio = await GpioController.GetDefaultAsync();

            APhase = Gpio.OpenPin(19);
            BPhase = Gpio.OpenPin(6);

            APhase.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
            BPhase.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);

            Pwm = await PwmController.GetDefaultAsync();
            Pwm.SetDesiredFrequency(1000);

            AEnable = Pwm.OpenPin(26);
            BEnable = Pwm.OpenPin(13);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private bool stopMove = true;

    private double speed = 1;

    public void StopMove()
    {
        stopMove = true;
    }

    public async Task MoveForward()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        stopMove = false;

        APhase.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
        BPhase.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);

        AEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(speed);
        BEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(speed);

        Debug.WriteLine("Starting...");

        AEnable.Start();
        BEnable.Start();

        while (!stopMove) { }

        AEnable.Stop();
        BEnable.Stop();

        AEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(0);
        BEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(0);
    }

    public async Task MoveBackward()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        stopMove = false;

        APhase.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        BPhase.Write(GpioPinValue.High);

        AEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(speed);
        BEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(speed);

        AEnable.Start();
        BEnable.Start();

        while (!stopMove) { }

        AEnable.Stop();
        BEnable.Stop();

        AEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(0);
        BEnable.SetActiveDutyCyclePercentage(0);
    }
```

Does anyone know any working solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can have a try:

First, using Microsoft.IoT.Lightning library. There are two PWM control providers:

- [Software simulate PWM](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning/blob/c99fd70eed50178421c4607337a43664d9b162a0/Providers/PwmDeviceProvider.cpp#L31). But you can see the [max frequency is 1kHz](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning/blob/c99fd70eed50178421c4607337a43664d9b162a0/Providers/PwmDeviceProvider.h#L68). In order to use higher frequency you can modify the constant and reference the lightning source code for you project, instead of the nugget one. However, Since it’s using software timing, you might have slewed waveforms in you make aggressive attempt.
- [PCA9685](https://github.com/ms-iot/lightning/blob/c99fd70eed50178421c4607337a43664d9b162a0/Providers/PwmDeviceProvider.cpp#L30). For doing this you need [a external PCA9685 module and some electronic circuits](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/arduino-wiring/dcmotor). Likewise, you need reference source code the modify the max frequency that defined.

Second, using the out of box driver BSP. This driver support on-chip PWM hardware. Try to use higher frequency to see if the signal generated meets your requirement.

Comment: I've tried to modify this library, but build process throws "Payload file '(my desktop dir)\lightning-develop\Providers\Microsoft.IoT.Lightning.Providers.targets' does not exist."